# Função dentro do servidor sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer uma função dentro do servidor sql, porém, não consigo utilizar ela por conta de aparecer um erro dizendo que o resultado consiste em mais de linha (Error Code: 1172 Result consisted of more than one row) queria saber como posso resolver isso

```
`CREATE FUNCTION `retornaSolo`(id int(11)) RETURNS varchar(80) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
declare solos varchar (80);
select tipo_solo into solos from solo where status_solo = 'Ativado' 
and cod_usuario = id;
RETURN solos;
END`
```

Comment: o que você quer retornar com a função ? apenas um dado ? vários dados ? uma tabela ?

Comment: http://tsqlmaster.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/criando-uma-procedure-com-cursor-no.html     .... Este"into" permite o retorno de apenas um valor , seu select "ativados" deve retornar mais de uma linha , leia sobre cursores.

Comment: eu pretendo retornar varios dados, que no caso seriam todos os tipos de solos cadastrados pelo usuario

Answer (score 0):

Função retorna apenas um resultado, o que você pode fazer é criar uma stored procedure, ou trazer os resultados concatenados e separados por "," que seria mais ou menos assim:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS retornaSolo;
CREATE FUNCTION `retornaSolo`(id int(11)) 
RETURNS varchar(80) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN

    DECLARE solos varchar (80);

    SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tipo_solo SEPARATOR ',') 
    INTO solos 
    FROM solo 
    WHERE status_solo = 'Ativado' 
    AND cod_usuario = id;

RETURN solos;
END;
```

ou a stored procedure que seria assim:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_retornaSolo;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_retornaSolo(id INT(11))
BEGIN

    SELECT
        tipo_solo
    FROM solo
    WHERE status_solo = 'Ativado'
    AND cod_usuario = id;


END
|
DELIMITER ;
```